# Unir dos Arrays (ventas - detalles)

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo estos dos array en JSON:

**ventas:**

```
[
  {
    "id_venta": "27",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "serie_documento": "F001",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  }
]
```

**detalles:**

```
[
  {
    "id_venta_detalle": "35",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "descripcion": "CERT. FIRMAS PN",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  },
  {
    "id_venta_detalle": "34",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "descripcion": "LEGALIZACION COPIAS",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  },
  {
    "id_venta_detalle": "33",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000001",
    "descripcion": "CERTIF. FIRMA P. JURIDICAS",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  }
]
```

Quiero unir `ventas` con `detalles` en un solo array relacionando con su código, que salga así por ejemplo:

```
[
  {
    "id_venta": "27",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "serie_documento": "F001",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  },items:[
   {
    "id_venta_detalle": "34",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "descripcion": "LEGALIZACION COPIAS",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  },
  {
    "id_venta_detalle": "33",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000001",
    "descripcion": "CERTIF. FIRMA P. JURIDICAS",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  }]
]
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?... Con JavaScript lo podrías hacer...

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues un [example] para que sea más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo explícitamente a lo que pides, **Unir dos Array Json**, te lo explico.

1. Primero pasas los Json a array con **json_decode()**.
2. Luego creas un nuevo array uniendo los 2 anteriores.
3. Por ultimo vuelves a pasarlo a Json con **json_encode()**.

```
    $ventas = '[{"id_venta":"27","codigo_interno":"F00100000002","serie_documento":"F001","numero_documento":"00000002"}]';

    $detalles = '[{"id_venta_detalle":"35","codigo_interno":"F00100000002","descripcion":"CERT.FIRMASPN","numero_documento":"00000002"},{"id_venta_detalle":"34","codigo_interno":"F00100000002","descripcion":"LEGALIZACIONCOPIAS","numero_documento":"00000002"},{"id_venta_detalle":"33","codigo_interno":"F00100000001","descripcion":"CERTIF.FIRMAP.JURIDICAS","numero_documento":"00000002"}]';

    $arrayVentas = json_decode($ventas, true);
    $arrayDetalles = json_decode($detalles, true);

    $arrayResult = [
        $arrayVentas,
        $arrayDetalles
    ];

    echo json_encode($arrayResult);
```

Puedes pasar mi código a [este PHP Fiddle](https://www.proose.com/tools/php-fiddle) y probar y formatear el Json resultante en este [Json Parser](https://jsonformatter.org/)

---

Recuerda marcar la pregunta como aceptada si te funciona.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que tienen que relacionarse con el `codigo_interno` de ambos, es decir, si coinciden, va el detalle en la venta, si no, no va.

Comment: Cierto, pasé por alto ese detalle, pero eso es algo se maneja con la petición de los datos. Me imagino que el OP hará un filtro por `codigo_interno`, así cuando llegue al paso de unir las "ventas" mas los "detalles" en un solo array Json no tendría problemas. Voy a editar la respuesta para mostrar el resultado en base a un `codigo_interno`.

Comment: Es mas, en el ejemplo del OP, en el resultado muestra los detalles de los dos `codigo_interno`.

Answer (score 0):

pero mas que unir solamente es armar la estructura del array asi:

```
[
  {
    "id_venta": "27",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "serie_documento": "F001",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  },items:[
   {
    "id_venta_detalle": "34",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "descripcion": "LEGALIZACION COPIAS",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  },
  {
    "id_venta_detalle": "33",
    "codigo_interno": "F00100000002",
    "descripcion": "CERTIF. FIRMA P. JURIDICAS",
    "numero_documento": "00000002"
  }]
]
```

Fíjate que dentro de del array hay otro array que esta relacionado con el índice CODIGO_INTERNO.

Comment: Hola MIGUEL, te sugiero que mires [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.